# Layout for module

Tags: php, zend-framework2

How i can create own layout for each modules?
I have NavBar and i want to know what subpage is active.

Default module.config in Application module contains:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
            'template_map' => array(
        'Album/layout'  => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
    ),

),
```

layout.phtml:

```
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo $this->url('home') ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Home') ?></a></li>
                <li ><a href="<?php echo $this->url('album') ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Kontakt') ?></a></li>
            </ul>
```

When I'm on Home subpage 'home' button is active, but when I'm on Album subpage, 'home' button is also active. How to fix it? Should I create own layout for Album module? When I have to, how?

Comment: check this https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpModuleLayouts

Comment: I posted babak faghihian's comment as an answer because that's what it is, and so Tk000 can accept it as an answer.

Comment: Different layout for each module isn't the solution for your problem. You should use [Zend\Navigation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.navigation.view.helper.menu.html) for that.

Answer (score 1):

As  babak faghihian suggested in the comments, use [EdpModuleLayouts](https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpModuleLayouts)